# How to show AppTrackingManager pop-up on iOS 15.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, popup, openedx

I am trying to implement pop-up for apptracking in iOS 15.1 as they have rejected my application.
But pop-up is not appearing in my device and simulator as well.

1. Added AppTransparencyFramework in Framework , Libraries and Embedded content [General Tab].
2. Also made it optional in [Build phases]
3. Imported Library in OEXAppDelegate.h file
4. Implemented following code in OEXAppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application

    applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {



    [self requestIDFA:launchOptions];

    return YES;

}



- (void)requestIDFA :(NSDictionary*) launchOptions{



    if (@available(iOS 15, *)) {



        [ATTrackingManager requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler:^(ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus status) {



            // Tracking authorization completed. Start loading ads here.



            // [self loadAd];



            printf("status");



        }];



    } else {



        printf("status");



        // Fallback on earlier versions



    }



}
```

Comment: Where do you call this function?  You can't call it in `didFinishLaunching`

Comment: Can you please share app rejection information.

Comment: Calling it in applicationDidBecomeActive.